# Multiple SPGridView filtering issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, spgridview

I created two visual webparts having an SPGridView with filtering enabled. Both SPGridViews use an ObjectDataSource (not the same instance, each SPGridView has its own ObjectDataSource).

The filtering works fine as long as there is only the one webpart in the page. But after I add the second webpart, the clear-filter of the SPGridView works only on the first added webpart.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,
Panos